Quarkus Tests are not dynamically added/removed in dev mode
I am running a sample project from quarkus.io/ with only  quarkus-rest-jaxb and tests dependencies.
I am running quarkus:dev and it only shows the initial test, even after closing the process then running it again, it won't reflect the new/modified/deleted tests.
After mvn clean package it is only adding the tests from the GreetingResourceTest but any newly added test are not reflecting.
I am using         <quarkus.platform.version>3.10.2</quarkus.platform.version>
Expected behavior:
Once I add a new tests to dynamically reflect in dev mode as mentioned in the book Quarkus-For-Spring-Developers and I quote

To enable continuous testing, return to the terminal and execute ./mvnw quarkus:dev.
Once the Quarkus banner appears, notice in the terminal the following text at the very
bottom: Tests paused, press [r] to resume.

Also:

Return to the terminal and notice that Quarkus automatically ran the test successfully.
Also notice that only one test was run: the test that was just created. The existing test in
the GreetingResourceTest.java class was not rerun


Use mvn quarkus:test instead for continuous testing. This will auto detect any changes and run the tests automatically.

Same, even if I press r to rerun tests it only runs the ones I had when I ran mvn quarkus:test
